Mapping a surface integral to the unit sphere
I want to calculate an integral over a region of the unit sphere,
$$
I = \int_D f(\theta,\phi) d\Omega
$$
where $D$ is a subset of the unit sphere. I have seen some authors state (e.g. Atkinson 1980), that if you can find a 1-1 mapping between $D$ and $S^2$, then you can convert the integral into "standard form", e.g. an integral over the full unit sphere $S^2$. I am trying to see how this works. Suppose I find a 1-1 mapping,
$$
u: D \rightarrow S^2
$$
Then is it true that
$$
I = \int_{S^2} f(u(\theta_D,\phi_D)) d\Omega
$$
? I have used $(\theta_D,\phi_D)$ to indicate these are locations in $D$. I'm not sure how the above integral is of any use for calculations. Ultimately I want to calculate the integral (using numerical methods), assuming that the map $u$ is known. Does anyone know how to proceed?

This makes no sense. If $f$ is defined only on $D$, how is the second integral even defined?

"Change of variables for a double integral" at https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/changeofvariables.aspx may be a useful resource for understanding Answers here.

@Ted, yes I agree, the question is how to properly define the integral over $S^2$ using the map $u$. Also, lets assume that $f$ can be easily extended from $D$ to $S^2$ - it is just a function of $(\theta,\phi)$

@Eric, thanks, those notes might be what I need

You need to pull back by $u^{-1}$, not $u$, and this includes transforming the surface area measure, too. This is the change of variables formula.
